# Error in template flask run AndreiD/Flask-Easy-Template

Tags: python, templates, flask

Good Morning!
I am a beginner in the python / flask world ... I found [this template](https://github.com/AndreiD/Flask-Easy-Template) and found it complete and simple, good for beginners and with some interesting features.

I just can not run this template. It has some packages that do not install by pip (pycrypto==2.6.1, python-cloudfiles==1.7.11, python-loaders==0.2.3).
Was this a reason? Can anybody help me?

I need some help to run this template.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhhr6.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you do ```pip install -r requirements.txt```?

Comment: The owner of the repo seems to anticipate issues and gave instructions on solving them. Eg. "Error install module Pycrypto : microsoft visual c++ compiler for python 2.7  is required -> Do this... ". Have you tried it? Did that work?

Comment: I was able to install the missing modules (pycrypto==2.6.1, python-cloudfiles==1.7.11, python-loaders==0.2.3) . But, it is not running yet.

Answer (score 0):

This project is unmaintained, please try [this one](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask) instead.

For your question, `flask.ext.foo` is the old way to import extension and it is removed in Flask 1.0. If you want to fix it, try the methods below:

**Method 1**: Fix old import statements

Find these lines in `application/__init__.py`:

```
from flask.ext.cache import Cache
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

change them to:

```
from flask.cache import Cache
from flask.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

**Method 2**: Use a virtual enviroment

Everything will be ok if you use the pinned version in the project's requirement file. Just create a virtual enviroment with virtualenv, pipenv, poetry, venv etc, activate the virtual enviroment, then install dependency from the requirements.txt file.